# DHCP issue in our network, could it be hidden 2nd DHCP server?

Tags: linux, dhcp, dhclient

Something weird happened today. We have a TP-LINK wifi router in our office distributing a pool of IPs 192.168.80-200. There are some windows and some linux boxes.

One of the linux boxes (CentOS) today booted up with IP 192.168.25.X.

I tried renewing the lease on my PC (Ubuntu) expecting to get 192.168.1.X, but here is what happened:

$ sudo dhclient r
$ sudo dhclient eth0
(long wait)
$ ifconfig eth0
inet addr:192.168.25.251

After a few minutes I renewed it again and it came with correct 192.168.1.81 (and from that point for now it is staying correct in every re-newal)
Where from that another network came up?
Later I remembered I could add `-v` to `dhclient` to see some more verbose info especially which DHCP server is responded to my request.

Could it be another DHCP server in our network I'm not aware of? I tried looking in /var/lib/dhcp leases but couldn't find traces of the 25th network.

It seems the windows PCs are not affected, only the linux boxes.

Comment: Addition: It seems the DHCP server started serving only correct IPs after its setting for "SPI firewall" has been turned off. Could it be TP-LINK related issue?

Comment: release your lease, run a `tcpdump port 67 or port 68`, start dhclient again and see if an unexpected server is answering your DHCP DISCOVER requests with DHCP OFFER responses and an address from the 192.168.25.0/24 network. The reason why it *normally* works could be because your TP-LINK rotuer usually responds faster but failed to do so at one time or the other.

Comment: This is a very good idea. Currently I can't see anything other than the TP-LINK answering with DHCP OFFER. Maybe the hypothetical rogue server is turned off right now. If the situations arise once more I will try your suggestion. Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows hosts, you could try the [DHCPloc utility](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DHCPLOC-Utility-34262d82) which is also available as part of the Support Tools package from the Windows installation CD/DVD:

> This utility also serves as a great security application as it can detect the presence of unauthorized DHCP servers on your network. This is a great way of eliminating rogue routers and access points that may be sourcing DCHP packets.
>
> Syntax :
>
> ```
> dhcploc /p /a:"AlertNameList" /i:AlertInterval ComputerIPAddress [ValidDHCPServerList]
> ```

then you'll know.

Comment: Although I  see you run Linux, this is an under rated tool. Do the tcpdump method in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your hosts normally get addresses from the correct scope and only occasionally from the rogue scope could be because your TP-LINK rotuer usually responds faster but failed to do so at one time or the other.

To locate rogue servers you could:

1. release the client lease
2. run a `tcpdump port 67 or port 68` at the client side
3. start dhclient again and see if an unexpected server is answering your DHCP DISCOVER requests with DHCP OFFER responses and an address from the 192.168.25.0/24 network
4. note this server's MAC address and locate the switch port connecting it using the FDB / MAC address table lookup from your switches' management interface